# GeoServer LDAP Authentication 'Test Connection' succeeds, but login fails

Tags: geoserver

I am attempting to use Active Directory for GeoServer authentication.  When I click the 'Test Connection' button on the Admin > Authentication > Providers > LDAP settings page, it says "Connection Successful."  However, when I log out of Geoserver, and try to log in with the same credentials, I get an "invalid username/password combination" error.

My LDAP settings are as follows, where `ADserver`=my Active Directory server, and `domain`=my company domain:

Server URL: `ldap://ADserver/dc=domain,dc=com`
TLS: `[Not checked]`
User lookup pattern: `[empty]`
Filter used to lookup user: `(userPrincipalName={0})`
Format used for user login name: `{0}@domain.com`
Use LDAP groups for authorization: `[Not checked]`
User Group Service: `default`

And I have selected this Authentication Provider in my Provider Chain.

Why does the Test Connection succeed, but actually logging in fails?

Comment: Have checked your AD server configuration? In particular, does it match the TLS configuration here? [I know that this isn't what you asked, but clearly there is a difference somewhere, and you'd probably be happy if it just worked]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I eventually got the LDAP login to work:

1. Added a Group (`LDAPGroup`) to my `default` User Group Service and selected appropriate roles for the group
2. Added each LDAP user to my `default` User Group Service as a member of `LDAPGroup`.  When you do this, you have to create a password for each user, but GeoServer will ignore it and authenticate against LDAP. Use something my  like "fake" for the password.
3. In my Provider chain, I had both `default` and `myLdapProvider` selected.  Curiously, it only worked when `default` was listed first in the Selected text box.  When I had `myLdapProvider` first, login failed.  Not sure why, but that was the biggest stubling block for me.

I hope this helps someone else avoid the same frustrations I had.

Answer (score 2):

I got a solution working on GeoServer 2.7.2 that was very similar to @xcer however I didnt need to add an extra Group, as adding the users to the `default` User Group Service seemed to be enough for me.

In short:

1. I added an LDAP authentication provider (much the same as in the question above) with User Group Server pointing to `default'. Connection tested OK.
2. Under menu section 'Users, Groups, Roles' I opened tab 'Users/Groups' and proceeded to add each user manually with a random password and ADMIN role.
3. In the Provider Chain, I also had `default` listed first, and my `ad-ldap` authentication provider listed second.

I found that this:

1. Enabled me to log in using either password (ie the one via Active Directory / LDAP, as well as the manual password I provided for each user).
2. Once I logged in (using either password), the permissions that got applied were the ones in the `default` User Group Provider that can be added and modified manually via the interface.

Not sure if this was the intended way to get it working - it would have been a better solution overall if I could just apply permissions via LDAP groups. But after battling with Geoserver for 3 hours solid that was the best that I could manage.

Comment: I just tested this, and you are right, the Group inside the `default` User Group Service is not necessary.  I still needed those Groups for other reasons, but not to get the authentication working.

Answer (score 0):

I was also struggling with this problem for 2 hours now! The answer of xcer helped me:

> In my Provider chain, I had both default and myLdapProvider selected.
>   Curiously, it only worked when default was listed first in the
>   Selected text box. When I had myLdapProvider first, login failed. Not
>   sure why, but that was the biggest stubling block for me.

For me, it only worked when I had myLdapProvider first! If default was listed first, the login failed. Pretty strange!

Answer (score 0):

Using version 2.16.0 I found that by Creating a basic AD connection, I showed as green for testing a user account. As soon as I logged out and attempted to login it failed with the logs stating "Bad Credentials".

I had to navigate to Security --> Authentication and migrate my Authentication Provider I created from the "Selected" panel of the "Provider Chain" to the "Available" side (pretty much disabling it). I then saved, moved it back to the Selected panel and saved again. AD authentications began working again.